# Add column from filename as date

Tags: python

I am new to python and do not have previous programming background. However, I am planning to take a python programming course offered by my Univ. this Fall. I have a small project to complete but I need to deal with more than 5 GB of small text files (each is 50 kb).

I have a lot of files with filename as 20130325rand.dat. The file has 3 lines of header (which I need to get rid of). I need to create a column and add the first 8 characters from the file name in that column as date (mm/dd/yyyy).

Also, I need to calculate averages of every 12th row of the variables that are in the file (readings measured every 5 min, need to calculate hourly averages). I know this is lot of work but I would greatly appreciate any suggestions, directions and help. Thanks.

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: Also, if at all possible, post usable data (or a link to usable data posted elsewhere) instead of screenshots. Nobody can debug or test code against a screenshot.

Comment: This site is for specific questions (and in principle, only one at a time) whereas you seem to have either a general question ("how do I program?") or lots of specific questions ("how do I do this in Python?", "how do I do that in Python?", "how do I do this other thing in Python?").  It's good that you plan to take a course, but if you need to get a task done before then, you'll have to do some reading on your own.  Try [these links](http://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/NonProgrammers) for some ideas, and of course anything else you can find on Google.

Answer (score 1):

Some pointers:

Reading a text file into a list of lines:

```
with open('20130325rand.dat') as df:
    lines = df.readlines()
```

This will give you a list of lines, e.g.

```
In [17]: lines
Out[17]: ['# header 1', '# header 2', '# header 3', 'line 0', 'line 1', 'line 2', 'line 3', 'line 4', 'line 5', 'line 6', 'line 7', 'line 8', 'line 9', 'line 10', 'line 11', 'line 12', 'line 13', 'line 14', 'line 15', 'line 16', 'line 17', 'line 18', 'line 19', 'line 20', 'line 21', 'line 22', 'line 23', 'line 24']
```

To skip the first three lines an then get every 12th:

```
In [18]: lines[3::12]
Out[18]: ['line 0', 'line 12', 'line 24']
```

This is called [slicing](http://techearth.net/python/index.php5?title=Python%3aBasics%3aSlices). You can do the same for text:

```
In [19]: '20130325rand.dat'[:8]
Out[19]: '20130325'
```

The [online documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/index.html) for python contains a [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/). But there are many others available on the internet as well.

Welcome to Python, and good luck!

Comment: Thanks @roland-smith, [this](http://imgur.com/OGlMEa5) is what I used to read the directory and delete the first three lines and save the output. How would I calculate average for every nth rows? Any directions?

Comment: Append the values to a list. Take the `sum()` to the list and divide it by the `len()` of the list.